# How do I show that the matching polytope of $K_{2n}$ is a linear projection of the perfect matching polytope of $K_n$?

Tags: matching

Of course a matching polytope is the convex hull of edges in a matching and similarly for a perfect matching polytope.

Comment: Any thoughts on this? Any general direction?

Comment: Are you sure you have the subscripts right? The matching polytope of $K_{2n}$ lives in a dimension higher than the perfect matching polytope of $K_n$.